# Populate word template from excel vba

Tags: excel, ms-word, word-template, vba

On [this](https://stackoverflow.com/qu][2]][2]estions/26042519/excel-vba-to-open-word-template-populate-then-save-as-docx-file-somewhere-els) discussion it is well explained how to populate Word Templates from excel data using Bookmarks on Word.

In my case, I need to populate the template as many times as the Excel's rows are.

Attached you can find an example. Sorry if I don't add any VBA draft code, but I don't have any idea of how to set it up.

The excel table is:
[image]

The word template is:
[image]

And the result should be:[image]

Comment: I'm afraid the answer to your question is quite simple. It has to be done one step at a time, like, define the source document, define the target document, take the first item from source, place it in target, create a loop to repeat the action - done. Now, if your first step is to find someone who will take the trouble off your shoulders, this isn't the site for you. If your first question is how to define a document, you need a cours in elementary VBA. But if you did define the document and it doesn't work, then you would have code which we can help you put right.

Comment: @Variatus thanks. I haven't added the code because, as you say, it is a simple `for` statement. the problem is that I can't find any example that explain how to repeat a certain part of the template in loop.